# Hexapod Tcl Rotation script

Tags: tcl

I am new to TCL and am struggling with a code I wrote to perform a sinusoidal rotation (on the z-axis) with an hexapod (6-Degrees of Freedom robot). The problem is that, indeed, my hexapod performs a rotation of, i.e. 0.03 degrees, but when I want to plot the time series of the rotation motion, I see the hexapod is not doing the complete amplitude.

```
set TimeOut 10 
set code 0 

OpenConnection $TimeOut socketID 
if {$socketID == -1} { 
    puts stdout "OpenConnection failed => $socketID" 
    return 
} 


# Main

set T0 5000; #Time delay
set pi [expr 2*asin(1.0)]; #Pi
set period 20; #period is 20 second
set delta 0.2; #Time interval
set amplitude 0.03; #Amplitude(degree)
set step [expr $period/$delta];

HexapodMoveAbsolute $socketID HEXAPOD Work 0 0 -12 0 0 $amplitude; # Position(mm,degree) 
after $T0

for {set i0 0} {$i0<4} {incr i0} {
    for {set i 0} {$i<$step} {incr i} {
        set displacement [expr $amplitude*cos(2*$pi*($i*$delta+$delta)/$period)-$amplitude*cos(2*$pi*$i*$delta/$period)]
        set velocity [expr $amplitude*abs($displacement/$delta)]
        HexapodMoveIncrementalControlWithTargetVelocity $socketID HEXAPOD Work Rotation 0 0 $displacement $velocity
    }
}


# Close TCP socket 
TCP_CloseSocket $socketID
```

I expect an output of `0.03` degrees amplitude but what I get is `[+0.03, -0.01]` degrees. I'd appreciate any suggestion why I'm getting this output.

Comment: There's a saying in the Tcl world: [Brace your expr-essions](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Brace+your+expr-essions) -- you want `[expr {...}]` so the variables don't get expanded until you want to calculate the value. This *might* be the cause.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already tried and still doesn't work. I still have the same results...